# Display placeholder while results are loading

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that includes various blocks of information retrieved from db. Those blocks are arranged into sections and currently all that code is withing a long PHP page, so every time I load a page, there's a delay with its display. I would like to be able to load the page faster and place some sort of "loading..." or image placeholder in the section where the content will be loaded. I see it done frequently on other sites. How do I accomplish that? Do I need to break my long PHP page into:

1. Main layout page
2. Place each block with data from db into a separate page, and
3. Use includes to insert into main page.

How would I place "loading" while the content is being generated?

Just trying to better understand the process. I also use jQuery. Perhaps there's a pluging that can help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include in your main layout page only those elements that you would like to be visible when the page initially loads.  You should have placeholder elements with IDs that can be accessed via JavaScript where you would like content that you will be fetching from the server.

Use jQuery's ajax function to load the content from a separate request to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/script.php',
    data: 'any=get&variables=you&would=like&to=set', // can also be passed as an object
    success: function( html ) {
        // The argument passed to the success function is ALL of the output 
        // of your 'script.php'
        $('#containerid').html( html );

    }
});
```

In your backend PHP script, simply `echo` out the content that you want to show up.  You can optionally pass the content back as a JSON object, which is a more preferred method but requires more processing on the client side (the object must be parsed first before it can be accssed.  See PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function and [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) for more info on JSON).

Structured this way, it makes the most sense to me to make 1 ajax request per container that you would like to fill.

Please also check out the [reference page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for jQuery's ajax function

Comment: This is great! Do I understand you correctly, I need to create a placeholder, say <div id="containerid">loading...</div> and put loading image placeholder inside, and when the db-driven content is ready it will replace that placeholder image with compiled HTML from my external PHP page?

Comment: Yes.  The AJAX request will be made, and if it returns successfully the `success` function above will be called and passed all output (as a string) that the backend script produced.

Comment: Quick question. On my script.php page I have paging mechanism. When I had a long PHP page I would submit the page to php-self and get the pge re-compiled. Now that the results are included with an ajax on success, how do I getmy paging clicks to work? I can target the main page but then how do I call my ajax script? Or do I add similar JS code inside the script.php? Feeling a bit lost...

Comment: OK, I think I figured out. I've added inline PHP conditions inside AJAX function. Looks weird, but works. :)

Comment: Having PHP inside of JS works, but it's not ideal.  What kind of paging are you talking about?  You can add variables to the ajax request (such as currentPage, numberPerPage) that you can then use in your server side script to restrict what data you send back

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery the obvious way would be to let the PHP script build a skeleton page and then use javascript functions (Ajax) to load the different sections of the page, even do that in chunks so only parts of each section is loaded at each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can build one php file with page layout. Inside this file use AJAX to load data from all the blocks. You can use jQuery to make AJAX calls.

When you execute ajax calls you can put some animated gif "Loading...", there are lots of them if you search google "loading gif".

Hope it helps.